# Is it possible to populate a self reference in a mongoosejs schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema, mongoose

I have a mongoose model schema which I am attempting to build for some preexisting mongodb documents. The existing mongo documents have a self reference to the same collection. I have tried to create a schema which represents this relationship and then have attempted to make use of the [populate method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). The schema looks like the below (some properties removed for brevity):

```
var fileSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String },
    pcap: {
        files: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Files' }]
    }
});

var file = artifactConn.model('Files', fileSchema, 'info');
```

I then use the above model to query and then populate like this:

```
models.file.findById("91320684-9a1a-4f2a-a03f-63a7a208ec9b")
.populate('pcap.files') // have also tried just 'files' w/ the same result
.exec(function (err, file) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(file);
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

which results in this

```
{ _id: '91320684-9a1a-4f2a-a03f-63a7a208ec9b',
  pcap: 
   { files: [] }
}
```

If I check my document in mongohub it looks like this

```
{ "_id" : "91320684-9a1a-4f2a-a03f-63a7a208ec9b",
  "pcap" : {
    "files" : [ 
      { "_id" : "e4eed129-b4aa-46fc-8df2-3f3f92e6fe53" }, 
      { "_id" : "8c0ecb98-452e-475d-a521-feba5c3d1426" }, 
      { "_id" : "4b87c467-f396-4bcf-a7b0-8419e8441ec0" } ] } }
```

Am I doing something wrong with my call to populate? Is it the way that I have my schema setup? Is it the way the data is being stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your schema is incorrect. The schema you have would match a collection like this:

```
{ "_id" : "91320684-9a1a-4f2a-a03f-63a7a208ec9b",
  "pcap" : {
    "files" : [ 
      { ObjectId("e4eed129-b4aa-46fc-8df2-3f3f92e6fe53") }, 
      { ObjectId("8c0ecb98-452e-475d-a521-feba5c3d1426") }, 
      { ObjectId("4b87c467-f396-4bcf-a7b0-8419e8441ec0") } ] } }
```

The schema should be:

```
var fileSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String },
    pcap: {
        files: [{ 
            _id: { type: String, ref: 'Files' }
        }]
    } });
```

That should work.

Comment: It's no longer an empty set but is now instead `files: [ undefined, undefined, undefined ]`. It's at least reading the references now but is not populating them. Any other thoughts?

Comment: You'll also need to update the populate call to be: populate('pcap.files._id')

Comment: Unfortunately `.populate('files')`, `.populate('pcap.files._id')`,  have the same affect I still end up with `files: [ undefined, undefined, undefined ]`. However, `.populate('pcap.files')` throws an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined`. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: So you were mostly correct. I just had to tweak your answer slightly to use String instead of ObjectId. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Schema looks ok. Store the data the same way and you should be good: e.g.

```
{ "_id" : "91320684-9a1a-4f2a-a03f63a7a208ec9b",
  "pcap" : {
  "files" : [ ObjectId("e4eed129-b4aa-46fc-8df2-3f3f92e6fe53"), ObjectId("8c0ecb98-452e-475d-a521-feba5c3d1426"), ObjectId("4b87c467-f396-4bcf-a7b0-8419e8441ec0")] 
  } 
}
```

Then

```
Model.find(..).populate('pcap.files').exec(..)
```